# Position of modal dialog in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, modal-dialog

I'm not able to position the modal dialog box under the button in sencha touch using top and left config of Ext.panel because it always stay at a specific position which is defined through the element.style when I inspect element using chrome(I think it is from sencha touch library) with !important properties that I cannot override it through css as well. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the showBy method of components like

```
dialog.showBy(button);
```

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Button-method-showBy).

Comment: sorry but maybe you misunderstand my question. Here I still can show the modal but its poition is not directly under the button but very far on the left side. I have already tried using top and left config but nothing changed.

Comment: the showBy method can take 2 arguments. The other tells where to position the dialog. Im not sure what combination you will need for it to works. but the command should look like this dialog.showBy(button, "tl-tr?");. It documentaion has more explanation on the 2nd argument. If this doesnt work, you can try adding the positions in the 'style' attribute of the modal with !important. This should overide the properties set by the library.